# SettingWithCopyWarning Python pandas

Tags: python

tengo una consulta, quiero agregar una columna en un DataFrame de la siguiente manera:

```
df["nueva columna"] = 0

>>SettingWithCopyWarning: 
>>A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
>>Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Sin embargo al crear una columna de la siguiente manera:

```
df = df.assign(nueva_columna = 0)
```

no arroja ningun warning, pero no me deja ponerle espacio al nombre de la columna
Mi pregunta es ¿por qué me lanza la advertencia?, siempre creo las columnas de la primera forma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creo que el problema viene de que esa columna ya existía en tu DataFrame.

Cuando la columna ya existe,  al hacer `df["nueva columna"]` obtienes una referencia a la columna en cuestión, a la que puedes asignar perfectamente el valor `0` (que pandas repetirá el número de veces necesario para rellenar con ceros la columna completa). Pero el problema es que *tal vez*, bajo condiciones muy difíciles de prever, `df["nueva columna"]` no te dé una referencia a la columna, sino *una copia* de la columna. En ese caso la asignación de ceros la harías sobre la copia en lugar de sobre la columna real, y eso es lo que te dice el aviso.

El método con  `df.assign()` no tiene ese problema, pues actúa siempre sobre una referencia a la columna, ya sea para crear una nueva o para sustituir lo que ya había en ella si existía previamente.

No obstante, no es esa la única solución. El propio *warning* te está diciendo cómo deberías hacerlo, y es usando la propiedad `.loc`, del dataframe, la cual siempre te permitirá acceder a referencias de las columnas y nunca a copias.

La propiedad `.loc[]` espera dos índices entre los corchetes, separados por una coma. El primero se refiere a la fila y el segundo a la columna. Cualquiera de los dos puede ser un rango, por lo que te permite en el fondo hacer una selección rectangular de tu dataframe.

En tu caso, para seleccionar una columna completa, puedes poner `:`  en la parte de las filas. Por tanto:

```
df.loc[:, "nueva columna"] = 0
```

Eso creará la columna nueva si no existía, es decir hace lo mismo que tú intentabas, pero evitará el *warning*.

Answer (score 5):

Por empezar, dudo que el `warning` se de en un escenario de asignación simple como lo has indicado en tu ejemplo ya que en realidad este `warning` se implementó hace tiempo pero para operaciones encadenadas potencialmente problemáticas. Por ejemplo este caso:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3], columns=["A"])
df[df.A > 2]['B'] = 1000

main.py:4: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  df[df.A > 2]['B'] = 1000

   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

En primer lugar vemos que es simplemente un `warning` que no detiene la ejecución, en segundo lugar, nos sugiere cual es la forma adecuada de hacer lo que estamos intentando : `df.loc[df.A > 2, 'B']` y por último observando los resultados, vemos que no obtuvimos lo que esperábamos. El problema aquí es que `df[df.A > 2]` retorna una copia del `df` original, con lo cual la operación encadenada siguiente, es decir la creación de una nueva columna, actúa sobre la copia y no sobre el objeto original. Por consiguiente el retorno no es lo que potencialmente estaríamos esperando de ahí el `warning`.

La solución, en realidad pasa por hacer lo que se sugiere:

```
df.loc[df.A > 2, "B"] = 1000
print(df)

   A       B
0  1     NaN
1  2     NaN
2  3  1000.0
```

Por otro lado, si tenemos bien controlada la situación, tal vez convenga "apagar" este `warning`, por lo que podríamos hacer:

```
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
```

Answer (score 2):

El tema va porque se está asignando un valor único a toda una columna, por eso el sistema te indica que se precise una fila y columna.

En tal sentido, se tiene que crear un vector (`arreglo`) que tenga una longitud igual al número de filas del data frame. Sobre lo anterior se puede usar la función `shape` para saber las dimensiones del data frame (`df`)

```
# se crea un data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(["7", "4", "6", "10", "9"], columns=["Precios"])
print(df)
#   Precios
# 0       7
# 1       4
# 2       6
# 3      10
# 4       9

# dimensiones del data frame "df" (filas, columnas)
print(df.shape)
# (5, 1)

# se agrega una lista de ceros cuya longitud es igual al numero de filas df.shape[0]
df["Nueva Columna"] = [0] * df.shape[0]
print(df)
#    Precios  Nueva Columna
# 0       7              0
# 1       4              0
# 2       6              0
# 3      10              0
# 4       9              0
```

Aunque sugiero que trate de no emplearse espacios en los nombres de la columna, para ello se puede usar underline o el camel case