# Graficar toda una serie temporal tipo boxplot en un único gráfico

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy trabajando un *dataframe* donde el índice es un objeto *datetime* (series temporales) y la columna de datos es numérica.

Mi objetivo es agrupar los datos día a día y de cada uno de estos sacar su *boxplot* a fin de obtener diferentes métricas estadísticas.

Esta parte creo que ya la tengo gracias las funciones de `Pandas`, `groupby()` y `Grouper()`.

```py
groups = df2.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D'))
```

Lo que yo querría es graficar estos resultados.

Graficar de manera independiente cada uno de los días en un *boxplot*, lo he conseguido.

```py
groups.boxplot(figsize= (15,25), layout = (nrows, ncols))
plt.show()
```

Obtengo lo siguiente (hay más gráficos porque son varios meses pero ya se entiende):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Decir de estos gráficos, que me sale la hora 00:00:00 en el título que no me gusta y la querría quitar, pero bueno, es un mal menor.

La cosa importante viene ahora, graficar individualmente está bien, pero me gustaría graficar en un único gráfico todos los *boxplot* para poder observar mejor el comportamiento de los datos.

He llegado a conseguir esto,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con este código,

```py
groups = df1.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D'))
data = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x[1].values) for x in groups], axis=1))

data.boxplot(figsize=(20,5))
plt.show()
```

Pero además de que me da la sensación de haberme complicado la vida, lo más importante es que el eje X tiene ceros y no la fecha. Por lo tanto, ¿alguien puede ayudarme a hacer que salgan las fechas (imagino que vertical)? ¿Alguien sabe cómo hacer esto más simple?

NOTA: Se que la fecha la pierdo al hacer `x[1].values` pero no se como solucionarlo.

Dejo un ejemplo de como es mi *dataframe*:

```
           Temperature
Datetime    
2018-08-07 11:00:31 6.3
2018-08-07 11:10:31 11.4
2018-08-07 11:20:31 12.0
2018-08-07 11:30:31 13.7
2018-08-07 11:40:31 15.6
2018-08-07 11:50:31 13.6
2018-08-07 12:00:31 12.2
2018-08-07 12:10:31 11.2
2018-08-07 12:20:31 11.6
2018-08-07 12:30:31 12.4
2018-08-07 12:40:31 13.4
2018-08-07 12:50:31 13.2
2018-08-07 13:00:31 12.4
2018-08-07 13:10:31 11.7
2018-08-07 13:20:31 12.1
2018-08-07 13:30:31 11.8
2018-08-07 13:40:31 11.5
2018-08-07 13:50:31 10.9
2018-08-07 14:00:31 10.6
2018-08-07 14:10:31 10.4
2018-08-07 14:20:31 9.6
2018-08-07 14:30:31 9.0
2018-08-07 14:40:31 8.6
2018-08-07 14:50:31 8.1
2018-08-07 15:00:31 7.7
2018-08-07 15:10:31 7.3
2018-08-07 15:20:31 7.3
2018-08-07 15:30:31 8.8
2018-08-07 15:40:31 10.0
2018-08-07 15:50:31 11.3
2018-08-07 16:00:31 11.8
2018-08-07 16:10:31 12.3
2018-08-07 16:20:31 12.9
2018-08-07 16:30:31 13.2
2018-08-07 16:40:31 12.1
2018-08-07 16:50:31 11.1
2018-08-07 17:00:31 10.3
2018-08-07 17:10:31 9.6
2018-08-07 17:20:31 9.4
2018-08-07 17:30:31 8.7
2018-08-07 17:40:31 9.0
2018-08-07 17:50:31 8.3
2018-08-07 18:00:31 7.7
2018-08-07 18:10:31 6.8
2018-08-07 18:20:31 6.4
2018-08-07 18:30:31 5.8
2018-08-07 18:40:31 5.3
2018-08-07 18:50:31 5.2
2018-08-07 19:00:31 5.7
2018-08-07 19:10:31 6.8
```

¡¡Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Buen título, bien ilustrado y explicado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es:

1. Crear una columna solo con la Fecha
2. Construir el `boxplot()` por esta nueva columna

Algo así:

```
df1['Fecha'] = df1.index.date
df1.boxplot(by='Fecha', figsize=(20,5))
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Ya no pensé que fuese a tener respuesta y resulta que es algo muy sencillo! Me sele este *warning* `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead` ¿crees que se podría evitar o es más sencillo ignorarlo? ¡Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: El Warning que tienes es raro por que no parece que fuera a ser parte del código que te pasé, ocurre cuando haces cosas como estas `df[df.A > 2]['B'] = 1000`, revisa: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/253084/settingwithcopywarning-python-pandas